# Cross-entropy loss and stationary points

Tags: calculus, derivatives, entropy, logistic-regression, stationary-point

I am trying to find the stationary points of the cross-entropy function for binary classification :
$$
L(w) = -y \cdot \log(\sigma(wx)) - (1-y) \cdot \log (1-\sigma(wx))
$$
with
$$
\sigma(wx) = \frac{1}{1+e^{-wx}}
$$

If I develop and simplify I get:
$$
L(w) = \log(1+e^{-wx}) + wx(1-y)
$$

To find the stationary points in the close form I want to differentiate and solve for 0

$$
\frac{dL}{dw} = 0
$$
$$
\frac{dL}{dw} = \frac{-xe^{-wx}}{1+e^{-wx}} + x(1-y) = 0
$$
$$
\frac{xe^{-wx}}{1+e^{-wx}} = x(1-y)
$$
$$
\frac{x}{1+e^{wx}} = x(1-y)
$$
Here I start to face some problems:

- First, I am not sure that $x \neq 0$
- Second, $y \in (0;1)$, so obviously I am going to face some problems

What am I doing wrong and how can I solve this problem?

Thank you